# Magento 2 js Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: magento2, javascript

Im loading a custom module in my javascript file.
When in developer mode everything loads, but when switching to production, the script throws this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: InfoBox is not defined
```

Here is a part of my code:

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/template',
'text!./templates/result.html',
'text!./templates/result-popup.html',
// 'jquery/ui',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/jquery.visible.min',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/infobox',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/markerclusterer_compiled'
], function ($, mageTemplate, resultTmpl, resultPopup) {
    "use strict";
    $.widget('mage.StoreLocator', {
```

the file IWD_StoreLocator/js/infobox is generated to the path pub/static/frontend/theme/theme/en_US/IWD_StoreLocator/js/infobox.js

Edit:
I've tried to require the file like this:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'IWD_StoreLocator/js/infobox'
    ],
define([
```

How do i debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass the class to the function

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/template',
'text!./templates/result.html',
'text!./templates/result-popup.html',
// 'jquery/ui',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/jquery.visible.min',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/infobox',
'IWD_StoreLocator/js/markerclusterer_compiled'
], function ($, mageTemplate, resultTmpl, resultPopup, $Visible, InfoBox) {
```

I suppose jquery.visible.min don't return anything so you can move it in the last place and pass "InfoBox" as fifth argument